# Silverlight Dataform with multiple pages or tabs

Tags: silverlight, templates, datatemplate, dataform

I am looking at using the Silverlight DataForm for the first time to simplify Add/Edit/View of database records.

However the number of fields in the data I want to show will definitely result in a scrollbar. Now, I don't particularly like to use scrollbars if I can help it and neither do my users so I prefer to categorize groups of fields and put them on different pages (usually tabs labelled with each category). For example, 'Personal' on the first tab for name, e-mail etc. "Job" on another tab for job details such as work location, job title etc.

Is there a simple way to make the DataForm create pages. I presume that I need to create a DataTemplate for the ItemsSource. If so I have only done simple DataTemplates with TextBlocks and I am not sure if the complexity of splitting fields across Tab pages and specifying which fields are on which tab page is possible.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.